# Prolog - Find segment in a list of point

Tags: prolog

I need to find  a list of segments from a point in a list of slopes, every segment must be longer than 3 point, and have the same angle.

every slope are made from an angle and a point

```
slo(Angle,Pt(X,Y)).
```

Example:

```
find_segment(P,[slo(1,p1),slo(1,p2),slo(1,p3),slo(2,p4),slo(3,p5),slo(3,p6),slo(3,p7)],Ls).
Ls=[[P,p1,p2,p3],[P,p5,p6,p7]].
```

I have tried with this code, but i think that i have some problem(aganin) with the append,because

```
find_segment(_,[],_):-!.
find_segment(_,[_],_):-!.
find_segment(_,[_,_],_):-!.
find_segment(P,[slope(R,Ps)|Ss], Lines):-
(   test(R,Ss) %condizione
-> find_same(P,Ps,R,Ss,Nline),
  append(Nls,[Nline],Lines),!,
  find_segment(P,Ss,Nls)
; find_segment(P,Ss,Lines) %else
).
test(R,[slope(A,_),slope(B,_)|_]):-R=A,B=A.
find_same(P1,P2,R,Slopes,Result):-
   Result=[P1,P2|Lp],
   findall(P, member(slope(R, P), Slopes),Lp).
```

Some one can help me to find the right way to my goal?

EDIT:
I tried to change something in my code but still not working.
I change the function find_segment

```
find_segment(_,[],_):-!.
find_segment(_,[_],_):-!.
find_segment(_,[_,_],_):-!.
find_segment(P,[slope(R,Ps)|Ss],[L1|Lines]):-
(   confronta_test(R,Ss)
-> find_same(P,Ps,R,Ss,L1),
   find_segment(P,Ss,Lines)
   ;find_segment(P,Ss,Lines)
).
```

Now Swi-Prolog return me:

```
252 ?- find_segment(pt(1,1),[slope(6,pt(2,2)),slope(6,pt(3,3)),slope(6,pt(4,4)),slope(0,pt(6,6)),slope(0,pt(7,7)),slope(0,pt(8,8)),slope(0,pt(9,9))],L).
L = [[pt(1, 1), pt(2, 2), pt(3, 3), pt(4, 4)], _G2019, _G2022, [pt(1, 1), pt(6, 6), pt(7, 7), pt(8, 8), pt(..., ...)], [pt(1, 1), pt(7, 7), pt(8, 8), pt(..., ...)]|_G2076].
```

Comment: In your example, where does `p` come from?

Comment: @luker From a list of point.

To help you to understand, I have a list of point, i need to find all the segments longer than 4 and insert it in a list.

but i'm working step by step.
My idea is to find all the slopes for one point, find the segment and after switch to the next point.

Comment: Your result for `Ls` has `p` but `p` does not appear anywhere in your inputs to `find_segment`.

Comment: @lurker, i have correct the example, the `p` is the `P `.`P` is the point over i'm working at this time. Every segment is made with P and 3 or more point.

Comment: A couple of things right off... you have overlap in your `find_segment/3` clauses. If the second argument is a list of one or two elements, it will match 2 of the clauses, not just one. I don't think you need 3 base cases. Secondly, your base cases use many `_` variables, which is causing the `_Gxxx` in your results. `_` is an anonymous variable. It doesn't mean "nothing" or "empty". It sort of means "anything".

Comment: @lurker i made 3 base cases because if you call `find_segment/3` with a slopes line made with one or two elements there is no segment.
With trace I think that the problem is the way that i chose to find the lines, because appends at the end of any `[Line]` some anonymous variable.
But I worked on the code all night but i have still not resolve the problem.

Comment: Your base cases indicate that `find_segment/3` succeeds with 0, 1, or 2 segments with anonymous results, and your recursion reduces down to those cases. It's not correct, and as I say, it is the reason for the `_Gxxx` variables in the response to your query. Your 4th clause accepts a list with one segment in it and makes the recursive call. So the logic doesn't at all match what you say in your comment.

Comment: You could start by trying to understand where the free anonymous variables in your answers come from (the `_GXXX`s), and then getting rid of them. You are going to only create more trouble for yourself if you keep on hacking on your problem while refusing to understand what the code that you write really means or does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a somewhat imperative use of Prolog to solve the problem. I would rather have written this in Ruby. ;) The idea here is to: (a) break the list of slopes up into sublists grouped by the angle value, then (b) select out the ones with length greater than 2.

```
find_segments(P, Segments, Result) :-
    segment_groups(Segments, SegmentGroups),
    segments_within_groups(P, SegmentGroups, Result).

segment_groups([], []).
segment_groups([P], [[P]]).
segment_groups([slo(N, P1), slo(N, P2)|Segs], [[slo(N, P1)|PH]|PT]):-
    segment_groups([slo(N, P2)|Segs], [PH|PT]).
segment_groups([slo(N1, P1),slo(N2, P2)|Segs], [[slo(N1, P1)]|PT]):-
    N1 \== N2,
    segment_groups([slo(N2, P2)|Segs], PT).

segments_within_groups(_, [], []).
segments_within_groups(P0, [SegGroup | SegGroups], Result) :-
    length(SegGroup, NumSegs),
    (   NumSegs > 2
    ->  maplist(slope_point, SegGroup, SlopePoints),
        Result = [[P0|SlopePoints] | R]
    ;   Result = R
    ),
    segments_within_groups(P0, SegGroups, R).

slope_point(slo(_, P), P).
```

Comment: thank you! i have resolved by my self this morning using the assert and changing the code. but this solution is efficient.